# Receive return value from different thread in another module

Tags: python, queue, ironpython, python-multithreading

I am trying to replicate `C#` code in `python` which executes a thread, waits for it to finish and returns a value. Essentially the method `RunAndWait` is in a helper class because a call to that method is being made multiple times.

`C#` code is as follows:

```
public static bool RunAndWait(Action _action, long _timeout)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Log.Message(Severity.MESSAGE, "Executing " + _action.Method.Name);
            _action();
        });
        if (!t.Wait(Convert.ToInt32(_timeout)))
        {
            Log.Message(Severity.ERROR, "Executing " + _action.Method.Name + " timedout. Could not execute MCS command.");
            throw new AssertFailedException();
        }
        t.Dispose();
        t = null;
        return true;
    }
```

In `python` I have been struggling with a few things. Firstly, there seem to be different types of Queue's where I simply picked the import that seemed to be working `import Queue`. Secondly, I receive a TypeError as below.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:/Users/JSC/Documents/Git/EnterprisePlatform/Enterprise/AI.App.Tool.AutomatedMachineTest/Scripts/monkey.py",
>   line 9, in 
>         File "C:\Users\JSC\Documents\Git\EnterprisePlatform\Enterprise\AI.App.Tool.AutomatedMachineTest\Scripts\Libs\MonkeyHelper.py",
>   line 4, in RunCmdAndWait
>       TypeError: module is not callable

Here is the `python` code for monkey:

```
from Libs.CreateConnection import CreateMcsConnection
import Libs.MonkeyHelper as mh
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue()
to = 5000 #timeout

mh.RunCmdAndWait(CreateMcsConnection, to, q)
serv, con = q.get()
```

and `MonkeyHelper.py`:

```
import threading

def RunCmdAndWait(CmdToRun, timeout, q):
    t = threading(group=None, target=CmdToRun, arg=q)
    t.start()
    t.join(timeout=timeout)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am fairly new to python. Could someone please help me out?

**Edit**

```
t = threading.Thread(group=None, target=CmdToRun, args=q)
```

correcting the line above brought up another error:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\threading.py", line 552, in _Thread__bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\threading.py", line 505, in run
>       self.**target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
>   AttributeError: Queue instance has no attribute '__len**'

Is that because `Thread` expects multiple args or because the `queue` is still empty at this point? From what I've seen is that the `queue` is just being passed as an argument to receive the return value. Is that the right way to go?

**Edit2**

Changed `t = threading.Thread(group=None, target=CmdToRun, args=q)` to `t = threading.Thread(group=None, target=CmdToRun, args=(q,))`

The change yields in a TypeError below, seems weird to me since Thread is expecting a tuple.

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\threading.py", line 552, in _Thread__bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\threading.py", line 505, in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
>   TypeError: tuple is not callable

Comment: You want `threading.Thread()`.  If you look at the error closely it will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`threading` is a module.  You likely mean to replace

```
t = threading(group=None, target=CmdToRun, arg=q)
```

with

```
t = threading.Thread(group=None, target=CmdToRun, args=(q,))
```

`args` is an argument tuple.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue. I see now module is `threading` while the object is `Thread`. Which brings up a new error. See edit.

Comment: Thanks again for helping out. I adapted second change passing `args=(q,)` which results in `TypeError: tuple is not callable`.